Dataframe larger than memory
In polars, pandas, or another dataframe library, is it possible to have a dataframe with data larger than RAM, as you can in DuckDB?
My current solution is to use the polars streaming API, polars.scan_.... However, whenever you want to create a new column, this requires scanning and sinking back the entire dataframe to disk, rather than just writing the new column to disk.
Thank you!

you can use memory-mapped file  to read data from hard disk. Another solution is to Reading Data in Chunks

Ok, great, thank you. Is there not a more direct way since polars runs on top of apache arrow? Can you have apache arrow files?
